# what happens when multiple processes try to read from the same pipe?

Tags: c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char buff[100];
  int pfd[2];
  buff[0] = '\0';
  pipe(pfd);
  if (fork())
    write(pfd[1],"hello world", 12);
  fork();
  read(pfd[0], buff, 100);
  printf("%s\n", buff);
  printf("goodbye\n");
}
```

I understand that only one process will write to the pipe, but what I don't understand is  could it be possible that one process reads from the pipe and reads only a part of the "hello world" and the other processes read the other parts of "hello world"?

In other words, what happens when a process tries to read a pipe while another process is reading it?

Comment: Why don't you run it ? We are not your compiler. Also `man fork` would be a good read before asking the question. If something isn't clear after reading the man page, come back to us, we'll be glad to help. Voting to close in the meantime.

Comment: You have _four_ processes running there, by the way :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo And all of them are going to try to read.

Comment: but what happen if a process try to read but another process is still reading before ?
 is the pipe closed for reading when a process read from there ?

Comment: @URL87: The pipe is not closed. The kernel will decide. Most likely the first reader will get the data, and the later ones will block while the pipe is still empty afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Demons will fly from your nose!](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/msg/dfe1ef367547684b?pli=1)

Actually if they're reading from the same pipe, then they're [holding file descriptors](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) pointing to the same [`struct file`](http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html) in the kernel. This means the kernel will determine who gets the data. Only one process will read any given byte.

Most reads and writes to pipes have some guarantees regarding [`PIPE_BUF`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman7/pipe.7.html), you might like to look into that.